# How can I remove/disable edit button from Address Information Block from sales order detail page

Tags: magento, magento2

As per specific order status I want to restrict user to make changes in order address i.e

I want to disable or remove the edit button from Billing & Shipping Address from Address Information block

Please check the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoFC.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find template responsible for this part of Sales Order View page. You could do this by enabling template debug in [Admin-Stores-Configuration-Advanced-Developer-Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sWbA.png)

This is the template that we need - vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

On lines 172 and 181 we have Edit link render

```
<div class="actions"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddressEditLink($order->getBillingAddress()); ?></div>
```

So what I suggest - is to override this template and add to it a ViewModel to process your custom logic. I will do this in my module - Vendor: Perspective, Name: SalesOrderCustomization

Create layout to override template - app/code/Perspective/SalesOrderCustomization/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml. You also could do this in your theme.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info"
                        template="Perspective_SalesOrderCustomization::order/view/info.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model"
                          xsi:type="object">\Perspective\SalesOrderCustomization\ViewModel\Order\View\Info</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy info.phtml to custom module app/code/Perspective/SalesOrderCustomization/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Modify template.
Add at the beginning (for me it is lines 30-31):

```
/** @var \Perspective\SalesOrderCustomization\ViewModel\Order\View\Info $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model');
```

Modify Edit link render:

```
/* Lines 175-177 */    
<?php if ($viewModel->isAddressEditAvailable($order->getStatus())): ?>
    <div class="actions"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddressEditLink($order->getBillingAddress()); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

/* Lines 186-188 */
<?php if ($viewModel->isAddressEditAvailable($order->getStatus())): ?>
    <div class="actions"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddressEditLink($order->getShippingAddress()); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And our ViewModel:

```
<?php


namespace Perspective\SalesOrderCustomization\ViewModel\Order\View;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class Info implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $orderStatus
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAddressEditAvailable($orderStatus)
    {
        if ($orderStatus === $this->getNotEditableStatus()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function getNotEditableStatus()
    {
        return 'complete';  /* todo: replace with Admin Configuration */
    }
}
```

Also add required files (etc/modelu.xml, registration.php).

Next step is to clean cache, enable module, do setup upgrade, and di compile (if needed).

**P.S.:** you should replace static status declare with Admin - Configuration menu (select or multiselect).